# Can I destroy a class instance even if there are still references?

Tags: debugging, vb6, activex, reference-counting

For debugging reasons I want to destroy a class instance which still as references. Is that possible? It doesn't have to be elegant or stable, because this'll never end up in production code.

To clarify:

```
Public Sub Main
    Dim o as MyClass
    Set o = New MyClass //o is created, one reference
    DestroyObject o     //Class_Terminate is called and the object destroyed
    //Further code, not using o
End Sub                 //Possible runtime error here (don't care)
```

Is that possible? One way would be to call `IUnknown::Release` to manually decrease the reference count, but how do I now how often I must call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very bad idea

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Private m_oRef As Class1

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim o As Class1

    Set o = New Class1
    Set m_oRef = o
    DestroyObject o
    ' releasing m_oRef after this point will bring down the IDE '
End Sub

Private Sub DestroyObject(pArg As Object)
    Dim lRefCount       As Long
    Dim lIdx            As Long
    Dim pUnk            As IUnknown

    lIdx = ObjPtr(pArg) + &H20
    Call CopyMemory(lRefCount, ByVal lIdx, 4)
    For lIdx = 1 To lRefCount - 2
        Call CopyMemory(pUnk, pArg, 4)
        Set pUnk = Nothing
    Next
    Set pArg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know, the object itself will call `Class_Terminate` when it thinks its reference count has got to zero, so your suggestion of calling `Release` should do the trick - just keep calling `Release` until `Release` itself throws an error.

[This page from Bruce McKinney's Hardcore Visual Basic](http://vb.mvps.org/hardcore/html/comraqs.htm) suggests one possible way that it might sometimes be possible to get the reference count, but I don't think you need to get into that unless this scheme (of `Release`ing till you can't `Release` no more) doesn't work.

"this'll never end up in production code" - careful with your assumptions, of course...

Comment: Of course, since this doesn't need to be ultra-stable Releasing until error is perfectly alright.

Comment: The reference count code you linked to works perfectly, even in VB6. The bad news: The VB compiler catches calls to Release. I guess I need another way around this.